# Trying to press on a <li onclick="....">text</li> python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried in 2 different ways to press on a `<li onclick="..">text</li>` object using:

```
self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[contains(., "+origin_iata_code+")]").click()
self.browser.find_elements_by_id('divcombo1').find_elements_by_tag_name('li').find_elements_by_partial_link_text(origin_iata_code).click()
```

origin_iata_code is part of the "text", the divcobo1 is id of the div i wanna press in.

the error im getting is that *a list object has no click() method*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `find_elements_by_xpath` which finds *multiple elements*, use:

```
self.browser.find_element_by_xpath()
```

watch the absence of `s` after `element`.

Comment: @DorAlt and that's a new problem now :)

Comment: now im getting there's no such element..
the origin_iata... is made from the list ['FLL', 'MCO', 'AFL', 'ATM', 'AJU', 'ARU', 'AAX', 'NVT', 'BRA', 'JTC',...]
and in the html there is 
<li onclick="selecionou('FLL', this,'.txtBusca1', 'true', 'origem', 'Estouem1', 'FLL');">Ft. Lauderdale - Miami (FLL)</li>